# Change circle position symmetrically on dragmove to another circle in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs, geometry

I drawed two circles with kineticjs,
I would like to change symmetrically the circle position on the dragmove of the first circle, this is my code.

```
newArc = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: mouse.x,
            y: mouse.y,
            radius: .25,
            fill: Color,
            stroke: "lightgray",
            strokeWidth: 3,
            draggable: true
        });
        layer.add(newArc);

        newArcMir = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: stage.getWidth()-mouse.x,
            y: mouse.y,
            radius: .25,
            fill: Color,
            stroke: "lightgray",
            strokeWidth: 3,
            draggable: true
        });
        newArc.on('dragmove', function() {
        newArcMir.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX());
        newArcMir.setY(this.getY());
    });
    newArcMir.on('dragmove', function() {
        newArc.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX());
        newArc.setY(this.getY());
    });
```

I got an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setX' of null ' in chrome related to this line

```
newArcMir.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX());
```

Comment: Can you make any jsfidle demo?

Comment: this is jsfidle demo http://jsfiddle.net/D2vbd/

Comment: You demo is not working, I mean it is broken.

Comment: Yes i have an error, i can't solve it in  newArcMir.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX()); 'Cannot read property 'setX' of null '

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was related with js global variable, kenetic didn't accept them, can't use setX or setY with a global variable.

so i created a local variable and i used them as follow

```
                    var drawTextTest = newArcMir;
                    var newArc2 = newArc; 
        newArc.on('dragmove', function() {

        drawTextTest.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX());
        drawTextTest.setY(this.getY());
                    });

    newArcMir.on('dragmove', function() {

                newArc2.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX());
            newArc2.setY(this.getY());


    });
```